# What is the best way to inspect the locators inside an Android app uiautomator or appium session?

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

I am a beginner in Android automation. I need to know to get the Android elements of an Android app, what is the best way? uiautomator or appium session?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android sdk itself having uiautomator.bat (`C:\Android\sdk\tools\bin\uiautomatorviewer.bat`) which can be used if you need to find the Android app element locators. But in Appium session you will be having more attributes for the elements in the inspecting screen. I have experienced that some of the elements showing ids when using appium session. Specially when the app is developed using react native.